# Access Object Values with Context API in Child Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I have the following object being exported into another file:

**info.js**

```
export const info = {
    companyName: '',
    title: 'Some title',
    year: '',
};
```

I'm importing this object into my Context.js like so:

**InfoContext.js**

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from 'react';
import {info} from './info'
export const InfoContext = createContext();

export const InfoProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
        ...info,
    });
    return (
        <InfoContext.Provider value={[state, setState]}>
            {children}
        </InfoContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

What I want to do is access the object values from my state inside my App.js. - Here is what I have tried but I am not having any success:

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { InfoProvider, InfoContext } from "./InfoContext";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <InfoProvider>
      <InfoContext.Consumer>
      {state => (
            <>
              <h1>{state.title}</h1>
            </>
          )}
      </InfoContext.Consumer>
      </InfoProvider>
  );
}
```

I'm clearly missing something obvious here. I've tried a few things but I'm not sure what the issue is. I feel it has something to do with my object being accessed from a separate file.

Additionally, here is a sandbox link with the above code. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-haze-vjqso)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing your value to Provider as array, but on Consumer you expecting it to be an Object.

You need to pass an Object instead:

```
<InfoContext.Provider value={{state, setState}}>
```

Also you are using Consumer wrong. As a callback it takes whole `value` that you've passed in Provider, not state:

```
<InfoContext.Consumer>
  {(value) => (
    <>
      <h1>{value.state.title}</h1>
    </>
  )}
</InfoContext.Consumer>
```

or using destructured assignment:

```
<InfoContext.Consumer>
  {({state}) => (
    <>
      <h1>{state.title}</h1>
    </>
  )}
</InfoContext.Consumer>
```

then you can use `value.setState({...})` for example. etc. But note that this is a bad practice updating state like that.

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-dream-8lbpx)

Comment: Thank you for the solution. - One more question if you don't mind... In regards to your comment about setting state like that as "bad practice", can you elaborate? - One of the things I want to do after accessing the state from my child component is change the values and use some of them in function declarations. - Is it better to create these functions and then pass them down as context?

Comment: @Dr.Tenma I think yes, better pass them down as the context. But you can look also at `useImperativeHandle` hook as well. See this https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle

Comment: anyway it's always depends on task you're working on and your application architecture. It's hard to say with so little information I have.

Comment: Thank you, I'm sorry for the confusion. I just wanted to know why setting `state` after passing context to another component would be considered bad practice.? - If I pass`setState` as a value in my provider and then use it to change the state of one of the values in my object are there any negative implications?

Comment: you can but again, this depeds on your project architecture